# Using <ui:repeat><h:inputText> on two list of string to print the first one and get the second one

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans

I am currently developing a web app in Java8 using JSF and PrimeFaces. I am succeeding in printing a first list of String using ui:repeat, but I cannot retrieve the answers of the user (which I want to add in the list reponses in the bean FormulaireComplete).

I must admit I don't know how to initialize a list of object in a.xhtml. It may come from here but I am really not sure. I have found some example on stackoverflow but the list had already been created with good number of element.

The class FormulaireComplete that will contains the responses (I did not put here the getter and setter but they are present in the code of course):

```js
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class FormulaireComplete  implements Serializable {
 private List<Reponse> reponses;

 public FormulaireComplete() {
  super();
  reponses = new ArrayList<>();
 }

 //validate form
 public String complete() {
  ReponsesDAO.create(reponses);
  return "../admin.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="postFormulaire" class="ui-g">
    <ui:repeat id="repeater" value="#{utilisateur.questionnaire.questions}" var="question" class="ui-g-12">  
        <div class="ui-g-12"><b>#{question.titreQuestion}</b> #{question.question}</div>
        
        <div class="ui-g-1"/>
        <p:inputTextarea class="ui-g-9" id="reponse" value="#{formulairecomplete.reponses.commentaire}" label="f"></p:inputTextarea>
           <p:selectOneMenu id="onemenu" class="ui-g-1" style="max-height:45px" value="#{formulairecomplete.reponses.note}" >
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "NA" itemLabel = "NA" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "1" itemLabel = "1" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "2" itemLabel = "2" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "3" itemLabel = "3" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "4" itemLabel = "4" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "5" itemLabel = "5" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "6" itemLabel = "6" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "7" itemLabel = "7" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "8" itemLabel = "8" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "9" itemLabel = "9" /> 
         <f:selectItem itemValue = "10" itemLabel = "10" /> 
           </p:selectOneMenu>
        <div class="ui-g-1"/>
        
        <div class="ui-g-2"/><p:separator id="separator" class="ui-g-8" /><div class="ui-g-2"/>
    </ui:repeat> 
    <div class="ui-g-5"/><h:commandButton id="validerForm" class="ui-g-2" value="Valider Formulaire" action="#{formulairecomplete.complete}"></h:commandButton><div class="ui-g-5"/>
   </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a data structure to map your question responses to your questions. I'd suggest creating a new type that wraps the question and answers together.

Data structure to associate questions and answers:

```
public class Response {
   private Question question;
   private Answer answer;
}
```

Managed bean that loads questions and answers separately and maps them into this new data type:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class FormulaireComplete implements Serializable {
    private List<Response> responses;

    public FormulaireComplete() {
        super();
        reponses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    init() {
         List<Question> questions = loadQuestions();
         List<Answer> answers = loadAnswers();
         for(Question q: questions) {
             for(Answer a: answers) {
                 if(q.id == a.id) {
                     this.responses.add(new Response(q, a));
                 }
             }
         }
    }

    //validate form
    public String complete() {
        ReponsesDAO.create(reponses);
        return "../admin.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

Display the data, with the answers initialized:

```
  <ui:repeat value="#{bean.responses}" var="response">
    #{response.question.description}

    <p:inputTextarea value="#{response.answer.input}"></p:inputTextarea>

    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{response.answer.score}">
      <f:selectItems ... />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
  </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I did not want to do so (because it involves some changes) but I think you are right, it is the best option ! Thank you @DavidZ !